# How do I receive windows volume name/label from its serial number?

Tags: windows, winapi

In my code, I have a volume serial number available to me, which belongs to a specific volume.

How can I programmatically get the label of the volume to which that serial number belongs?

[image]

There is a [`GetVolumeInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationw) function, but it provides all information associated with a root directory.

I searched for a Windows API for this, but couldn't find one.

Comment: [Enumerate all volumes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/enumerating-volumes), request [volume information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationw), compare the serial, and return the name if it matches.

Comment: @IInspectable why not post that as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

According to the IInspectable's suggestion:

[Enumerate all volumes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/enumerating-volumes), request [volume information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationw), compare the serial, and return the name if it matches.